# Filter Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have my dataset configured as

```
  var x = [
        {"phaseName":"Initiation","phaseID":"595e382f1a1e9124d4e2600c"},
        {"phaseName":"Execution","phaseID":"595e38321a1e9124d4e2600d"}
       ]
```

I want to write some function which give the output of filtered data.
For example

```
var y ="Initiation" 
samplefunction(y)
```

and i get the whole line of   `{"phaseName":"Initiation","phaseID":"595e382f1a1e9124d4e2600c"}`

Comment: would you like to test every property of the object?

Comment: Is the ```phaseName``` a key field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a simple `for` loop:

```js
var x = [{
    "phaseName": "Initiation",
    "phaseID": "595e382f1a1e9124d4e2600c"
  },
  {
    "phaseName": "Execution",
    "phaseID": "595e38321a1e9124d4e2600d"
  }
];

var y = "Initiation";

function samplefunction(value) {
  var newArr = new Array(); //creating a new array to store the values
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(x).length; i++) { //looping through the original array
    if (x[i].phaseName == value) {//check if the phase name coresponds with the argument
      newArr.push(x[i]); //push the coressponding value to the new array
    }
  }
  return newArr; //return the new array with filtered values
}
var result = samplefunction(y);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var x = [{
    "phaseName": "Initiation",
    "phaseID": "595e382f1a1e9124d4e2600c"
  },
  {
    "phaseName": "Execution",
    "phaseID": "595e38321a1e9124d4e2600d"
  }
];

function filter(phaseName) {
  return x.filter(item => {
    return item.phaseName === phaseName;
  });
}


console.log(filter('Initiation'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test all properties for the wanted value and filter the array.

```js
function filter(array, value) {
    return array.filter(function (object) {
        return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
            return object[key] === value; 
        });
    });
}

var data = [{ phaseName: "Initiation", phaseID: "595e382f1a1e9124d4e2600c" }, { phaseName: "Execution", phaseID: "595e38321a1e9124d4e2600d" }];

console.log(filter(data, "Initiation"));
```